# Excel formula to calculate joins between tables

Tags: excel, join

I have two tables and I have to calculate the values based on join conditions. Is it possible to do it with formulas?

The tables are like follows

Table1

```
RefT1 Value
A     7
B     2
C     5
D     4
```

Table2

```
RefT2 Value
B     5
D     8
E     7
```

I need to calculate:

> The sum of values of items in both tables
>
> The sum of the values in Table1 but not on Table2
>
> The sum of the values in Table2 but not on Table1

What formula can I use to achieve this?

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`, `INDEX()/MATCH()` or `SUMIFS()` should all be able to accomplish this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used vlookup & sumif, but I don't know how to get the conditional joins between tables

Comment: A true JOIN between tables could be produced with ADO. Adding a GROUP BY clause and you should be able to SUM on hte criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need three formulas

Both(an Array Formula):

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A5,D2:D4,B2:B5),SUMIF(D2:D4,A2:A5,E2:E4))
```

Enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

table 1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A5,D2:D4,0))),B2:B5)
```

Table 2: reverse the columns:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(MATCH(D2:D4,A2:A5,0))),E2:E4)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have to ListObjects / tables with the names Table1 and Table2 and the column names you have used in your example the following formula will give you the sum of items found in Table1 (which exist also in Table2):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Table1[RefT1],Table2[RefT2],0)),0,Table1[Value]))
```

In inverse thereof gives you the sum for all items in Table2 (which exist also in Table1):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Table2[RefT2],Table1[RefT1],0)),0,Table2[Value]))
```

Of course, the sum of both should be the "joining" sum of items:

[image]

<sub>Note, that all formulas are array formulas and as such must be entered using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. For more information on array formulas read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7</sub>

Comment: I just realized that I got the first and the second formula wrong. They are summing the items with a match in the other table while the OP asked for the opposite (with **no** match in the other table). Yet, since this is easily fixed and especially because @ScottCrainer got it right in his solution, I will leave this solution as is.

Comment: The phrase '*The sum of values of items in both tables*' may or may not mean '*The sum of values of items **FOUND** in both tables*'. The OP's narrative is ambiguous; someone should have a few words with the teacher who posed this homework question.